# Graphviz edge doesn't point to field in record if defined as part of a group

Tags: graph, graphviz, dot

I'm using Graphviz (and the dot language) to document the operations for a web app .  Since there are often many operations available on a page, I've been grouping the mappings for neatness and to prevent repeating myself.

However, I'm unable to get edges to point to the correct field in a record, when the edges are defined in a group.  Individually they work fine.

Before anyone asks, I realise record-based nodes are largely superseded by HTML-like labels.  However, those are too verbose for what I'm trying to achieve and I don't need the extra features, so I'm sticking with the original.

Here's a working example (you can try running it [here](http://magjac.com/graphviz-visual-editor/)):

[image: Graphviz output]

```
digraph site_map {

    // Pages
    {
        node[shape=component]
        
        page1[label="Page 1"]
        page2[label="Page 2"]
    }
    
    // Operations
    {
        node[shape=record style=filled fillcolor=green]
        
        entity1[label="Entity 1 | {<save> Save |<get> Get |<del> Del}"]
        entity2[label="Entity 2 | {<save> Save |<get> Get |<del> Del}"]
    }

    // Mappings: Page -> Operation
    {
        // Page 1 - short form (doesn't work)
        page1 -> {
            entity1:save
            entity1:get
            entity1:del
            
            entity2:get
        }
        
        // Page 2 - Long form
        page2 -> entity1:save
        page2 -> entity1:get
        page2 -> entity1:del
        page2 -> entity2:get
    }
}
```

In this example, the edges from `Page 1` end up pointing at the entities, rather than the specific operations within them.  Is there a tweak to my syntax which can make this work, or an I stuck using the long form?

Comment: I think you are stuck, but you might ask here:  https://forum.graphviz.org/

Comment: @sroush Thanks.  I've asked on the Graphviz site too.